# Newly-created file says it was modified 2 months ago

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems

I'm working on a 64-bit Windows 7 computer and I'm trying to create an installer for a TestStand project. Given that my root project folder is "haldex-testing", building the installer will create the subfolder tree `haldex-testing\bin\Installer\Volume1`; this subfolder tree does not exist prior to this. Immediately after building, the contents of this folder look like this:

[image: Installer folder]

After repeatedly deleting and recreating this subfolder tree, I'm finding that `setup.exe` consistently says it was *modified* on July 19th even though it's only been *created* today, along with all other files in the folder.

I don't know if this is actually going to create any problems or indicative of anything I should worry about, but I'm curious how this is even possible.

**EDIT**

In case it may be relevant, I'm also mounting the `Installer` directory as a read-only shared folder within a VMWare 64-bit Windows 7 virtual machine.

Comment: Isn't it just a copy of a "fixed" `setup.exe`?

Comment: @techraf What do you mean by "fixed"?

Comment: A copy of a file without a single byte changed. With all package customisations made in `.ini` and subfolders.

Comment: @techraf Ah, got you. I didn't know Windows behaved that way. I tried creating a text file and then copying it a minute later and yeah - the date modified for the new file stayed at 9:50 while the date created was 9:51. I always assumed that date created had to precede date modified, since intuitively you can't modify something before you create it. If you'd like to submit an answer explaining that Windows behaves this way, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a copy of a file in FAT or NTFS filesystems, the *modification date* will be preserved from the original file and *created date* will be set to one from the time of the copy.

Per [KB299648](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/299648):

> If you copy a file from C:\fat16 to D:\NTFS, it keeps the same modified date and time but changes the created date and time to the current date and time.
>
> If you move a file from D:\NTFS to D:\NTFS\SUB, it keeps the same modified date and time and keeps the same created date and time.

In your case `setup.exe` is a fixed-content executable file which does not change at the moment of creating a package.

Comment: And that is actually intended and sane behaviour - the contents weren't modified in either copy.